# C Language - Copy two different structure types

Tags: c, struct, copy

Is there any way to copy two different structure types, with similar content, without copying variable by variable?

For example, read a file, save to `pessoa` and copy to `xpessoa` assuming `email` is `'not defined'`.

```
struct pessoa {
    char nome[50];
    char telefone[20];
    struct{
    int dia,mes,ano;
    }data_nasc;
};

struct xpessoa {
    char nome[50];
    char telefone[20];
    struct{
    int dia,mes,ano;
    }data_nasc;
    char email[50];
};
```

Comment: that would work, but it's hazardous. You should create a sub-type instead of copying the fields in an anonymous struct and assign that sub-type field directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you are not allowed to change either structure than, you could do something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pessoa {
    char nome[50];
    char telefone[20];
    struct{
    int dia,mes,ano;
    }data_nasc;
};

struct xpessoa {
    char nome[50];
    char telefone[20];
    struct{
    int dia,mes,ano;
    }data_nasc;
    char email[50];
};

int main() {
  struct pessoa p = {"John", "111-222", {1, 2, 3}};
  struct xpessoa xp = { .email = "john@org.org"};
  memcpy(&xp, &p, sizeof(p));
  printf("name: %s email: %s \n", xp.nome, xp.email);
  return 0;
}
```

However as @dasblinkenlight said, this would be a very dangerous approach, since it would require to manually track the both structures.

Comment: I really couldn't change the structures. Thank you!

Comment: This is pretty dangerous. If `struct pessoa` had padding at the end that overlapped the `email` member of `struct xpessoa`, then the contents of `xp.email` would be clobbered by the `memcpy`. You could mitigate that by replacing `sizeof(p)` with `offsetof(struct xpessoa, email)` in the `memcpy` call. Technically, it's still undefined behavior, but most compilers will apply the same padding rules to the initial part of both structures and let you get away with it. (In this particular case, it is unlikely that `struct pessoa` has padding at the end.)

Answer (score 6):

An approach that is guaranteed to work is to embed the `pessoa` into `xpessoa`, like this:

```
struct xpessoa {
    pessoa p;
    char email[50];
};
```

This approach protects your code from undefined behavior in case `pessoa` layout is changed, because `xpessoa` no longer mirrors its layout.

Comment: Yes, it would work :)
But I need to do a (little) function where I copy all the content (without changing the structs) from one struct to another, and I am curious if I could copy the whole struct.

Comment: @JoãoRodrigues with the abovementioned structure, you can do `pessoa p = ....; xpessoa xp; xp.p = p;` with a simple struct assignment, no need for a function

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the "extended" structure to include the "base" structure as its initial member, the only legal way to copy the whole "base" structure into the "extended" structure is to define a union containing both structure types as members.

Quoting C11 section 6.5.2.3 (Structure and union members) paragraph 6:

> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible. Two structures share a *common initial sequence* if corresponding members have compatible types (and, for bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more initial members.

So you can define a union containing members of type `struct pessoa` and `struct xpessoa` and access the common parts from either member:

```
union upessoa {
    struct pessoa p;
    struct xpessoa xp;
};

int somefunc(void) {
    union upessoa a = { .p = {"Fred", "555-5555", {1, 2, 3} };
    // This is legal because data_nasc is part of the common initial sequence
    return a.xp.data_nasc.ano;
}
```

In my experience, a lot of code ignores this requirement for the structures to be members of a union, and assumes that if any two structures share a common initial sequence, the common initial sequence can be copied between objects of the different structure types; but this results in *undefined behavior* - it might work, but it isn't portable.